# Conditionals: continuous tense in if-clause

Tags: conditional-constructions, continuous

There are 5 types of conditionals, and I haven't found any with continuous tense in 'if' clause.

Suppose there is a long radio show. Eventually the presenter says something like 'the secret code is 555'. Listeners may call to the office, tell that '555' code and win some prize.

I can say something like:

- If he listens to the show, he may win a prize.
- If he had listened to the show, he could have won a prize.

But how should I say about the process (of listening) itself instead of the fact? I mean, the duration of the show may be an hour, but presenter tells the code on 5th (10th, 21st etc) minute. So, you should not listen whole show to win a prize - only 5 minutes (10, 21 ...) from the beginning is enough. 
I believe the examples above imply that the person should listen the whole show.

Could you please suggest? Thanks.

Comment: You can use continuous tense in the "if" clause, but it doesn't mean what you want it to. But that's not a problem, because the examples you give don't indicate whether the person listens to the whole show or not.

Comment: I think it's not quite clear what you're asking. I don't understand "But how should I say about the process (of listening) itself instead of the fact?"

Comment: @Silenus, will "non-finished process" clarify it?

Comment: So the person was listening for 30 minutes, lets say. And he still may win the prize. He should not listen to the end of the show.

Comment: Is this what you’re looking for? *“If  only he had been listening to the show during one of those times when the secret code was announced, he would have been able to have won a prize.”*

Comment: @tchrist - as example: [http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/]

Comment: There are far more than 5 sorts of conditional constructions; the so-called '0, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, mixed' which teachers use to introduce learners to conditionals only scratch the surface.

Comment: If I ***were or was listening*** to this discussion, I might not agree with everything that is said. fyi, it's "call the office** and "say the code"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to say that the person would only have to listen for the first five minutes to have won.

This could be said as: "If he had been listening to the radio show when they were announcing the code, then he could have won a prize."

Answer (score 1):

You need a *when* or *while* to do that.

> If he listens *when | while they announce the code*, he may win a prize.

Since listening will be an activity done over a stretch of time, expressing that with a continuous construction will be a bit better.

> If he is listening while they announce the code, he may win a prize.